# convert query to entity framework .net

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, subquery

The following query is working fine in SQL Server.

But how to convert it to Entity Framework?

```
Select * 
from Gp 
where Teacher_id IN (SELECT Teacher_Id
                     FROM TW
                     group by Teacher_Id
                     having sum(Credit_Total)  >= 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
var result = 
from g in Gp
    from teacher in TW
        group teacher by teacher.Teacher_Id into goupedTeachers
        where goupedTeachers.Sum(t=>t.Credit_Total) >= 15
where g.Teacher_id == groupedTeachers.Key
select g;
```